# How to clone a test plan from the TFS Test Hub (web UI)?

Tags: tfs

#### Question

- One can clone a test plan from Microsoft Test Manager 2017 (desktop application).
- How is that done from the TFS Test Hub (TFS web interface)?

#### Context

- In Microsoft Test Manager 2017, one can clone a test plan; see documentation [Copying and cloning test suites and test cases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh543843.aspx) and screenshot:
  [image: Clone a test plan]
- Microsoft seems to be moving more and more of the Microsoft Test Manager features into the TFS web interface called TFS Test Hub
  [image: Test hub]
- However, not all features of Microsoft Test Manager seem to be available in the TFS web interface
- Now, I'm not sure whether the clone feature hasn't been implemented yet, or whether I haven't found it yet on the UI or whether there is a new concept which replaces the cloning of a test plan

#### Links

- See some TFS Test Hub screenshots here: [Planning manual tests using the web portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd380763.aspx)
- Or here: [TFS Test Hub: What Does It All Mean? – Benjamin Day Consulting, Inc.](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/26/tfs-test-hub-meanings/)

Answer (score 0):

Until some time ago, the feature wasn't available on the web UI. That's why I didn't find it. But the feature was available on the backend as a service, so the documentation said to call a URL:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/clone%20operation/clone%20test%20plan?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

However now, it is also possible via the web UI. There is a `Copy test plan` menu entry in the hamburger menu:

[image]